# Choosing the appropriate tag to pass into the select method of BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

So I've been going through the online book "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python" and I'm learning about BeautifulSoup. My issue is I can't seem to figure out how to choose the appropriate tag based on what I find using the developer's tools in Chrome.

```html
<div data-hveid=.....>
  <div class="rc">
   <a href="https://www.python.org/".....>
        <h3 class="LC20lb">Welcome to Python.org</h3>
```

```python
# Using select to grab links to search results. 
linkElems = soup.select('r .a')
```

[An example of the inspector results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7O8q.png) 
In the book the goal was to grab all the links that show up on the search results page of a google search. To do so the author uses the line soup.select('r .a'). But when I use the inspector I get to the "a href" tag.

On my own I wanted to also grab the title/heading of a link that shows up on the search results page. The inspector highlights the "h3 class" tag. I tried to select that by telling select to look for tags with the class attribute equal to "LC20lb" but I keep getting an empty list as output.

So my question is, once the inspector has helped us narrow our focus how do we know which tag is the appropriate one to select? Like how did the author know that instead of the "a href" tag, we should instead go with '.r a' instead? In general, how far "out", i.e. which ancestor, should I choose once the selector has shown me a particular element?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason part of what I had written was not posted. I've added it in as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do 'a href' you haven't specified a div class, so it's going to get all instances of a href, which is going to include links to stuff like maps and drive etc. In the code you cite, you missed the "r" div class

```
    <div data-hveid=.....>
      <div class="rc">
        <div class="r">        
          <a href="https://www.python.org/".....>
            <h3 class="LC20lb">Welcome to Python.org</h3>
```

So soup.select('.r a') is getting all the a tags in the "r" div class (which is the search results), rather than all instances of a href tags.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: It does help thank you! So in general I should just grab the parent of whatever tag the inspector shows me?

Comment: I think the best way to think about it is as <a> tags being hyperlinks, and <div> classes being sections of the website, so if you wanted all the hyperlinks from a webpage you would use the <a> tag, but if you wanted all the <a> tags within a division of the website (in this case search results), you would want to use the div class in which they're located.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're help here finally made something click in my head and it all makes so much more sense now. Thanks again!